# Compatible version of microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection for WinForms Application with .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-4.0

I am working on Window Application `WinForms` with .NET Framework 4.0. I am trying to configure `microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection` but unable to sort correct compatible version. Is anyone have implemented DI with .NET Framework 4.0 app?

Comment: Why not upgrade the application to .NET Framework 4.6.2 or 4.8? MS.DI supports those versions. And otherwise, why not use a different DI Container that actually supports .NET 4.0? Do note that the most recent versions of most DI Containers do not support 4.0 any longer. The latest Simple Injector release, for instance, supports 4.5 and up.

Comment: Either way, seeking recommendations for software libraries, and more is off topic on Stack Overflow.